How to run honojs server application on github pages to use as an API server
having hono js application which runs on localhost:3000 and now wanted to use GitHub pages
in such a way that it works like an API server like many others
.
this is my hono based repo
see github pages
can someone suggest what need to done? I have added build script in develop branch but still unable to check how to run it and fetch data using API endpoints. do I need to add any script in github actions/workflow ?
xkeshav.github.io/o_ho_no/alphabet will return json list or whataver hono render as page

GHP is purely for serving static files, as many other questions cover.

use cloudflare adapter and it work.
gitHub pages for client side application only.
